# How to configure memcached properly?

Tags: linux, cakephp

I have configured memcached on linux. In `core.php` I coded like this

```
    Cache::config('default',array('engine'=>'Memcache'));
 Cache::config('default', array('engine'=>'Memcache','duration'=> 3600, //[optional]'probability'=> 100, //[optional] 'prefix' => Inflector::slug(APP_DIR) . '_','servers'=>array('127.0.0.1:11211'),'compress'=>false,));`
```

But it says `Warning: Cache not configured properly. Please check Cache::config(); in APP/config/core.php`

Answer (score 0):

You can't call both your cache configurations the same name.